# Hide contents of clipping mask layer in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is there a way to hide the contents of a clipping mask in photoshop? I don't want the clipping mask to show through in areas where the *clipped* layer is transparent.

Images might make it clear.

My layer setup:

[image]

Without clipping mask:

[image]

With clipping mask:

[image]

**Desired result:**

[image]

I know I can manually adjust the clipping mask to cover only the areas that the pattern covers, but that is too much effort since the pattern consists of a lot of layers and is quite irregular. Is there another way to simply make the clipping mask never show its own contents?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry to be blunt, but you are following the wrong approach.

A better way to achieve this, is to have the pattern as a regular layer, and give that layer a mask to hide parts of it. You can give a layer a 'Layer Mask' (a bitmap mask) by clicking the 'add a mask' button at the bottom of the layers panel while the desired layer is selected:

[image: add a mask button in layers palette]

You can then paint with black in the mask to hide parts of the layer, and paint with white to show them again. Greys correspond to a semi-transparency.

You can also add a 'vector mask', preferably by 'stealing' it off from a shape layer.

1. draw a shape layer, in the shape you'd like the mask to have
2. <kbd>command</kbd>/<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-drag the shape layer onto the layer to be masked in the layers palette
3. delete or hide the shape layer

Comment: I know that, but my pattern actually consists of a bunch of layers. I have updated the images in my question to make this more clear Does your approach still work then?

Comment: It does, if you just group the layers to be masked together and then apply the mask to the group.

Comment: Apply the mask to a layer group (your 'Clipped Group' for example). You can also use a vector mask if you prefer, which works the same way, but uses a vector path instead.

Comment: This solution doesn't work if your masking layer is a smart object.

Comment: @Keavon: no, but then you can alt-click the Smart Object layer to select all non-transparent pixels in there, and click the 'add a mask' button to create a mask from that.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to do it with a clipping mask instead of a layer mask (which allows you to use a smart object as the mask), see [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25409/nondestructive-gradient-as-mask#25419).