# How to create a nondestructive gradient mask over an object?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, gradient, mask

I'm trying to create a mask with a nondestructive gradient. So far I have managed to create my shape in a smart object and the masking gradient in another smart object.

My mask looks like this:

[image]

The image that I'm trying to mask looks like this:

[image]

By setting my image over this gradient smart object, I was able to produce the following:

[image]

The setup looks like this:

[image]

The problem is that it's also displaying the black from the clipping mask. I have tried turning down the fill on the masking layer but it also hides the image to be masked. I need to make the clipping mask work without displaying itself. I managed to create a *bitmap* layer mask which produces the desired result (below) but I need a non-destructive solution.

Desired result:

[image]

I need a way to not show the clipping mask layer and only use its transparency. I am also open to other solutions that can do the same thing, provided they are non destructive.

How can I create a non destructive mask over my target object, to achieve the effect I have shown in the final image?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Start with your gradient smart object set as a clipping mask for your artwork like so:

[image: Photoshop screenshot: starting setup]

Open up the **Blending Options** for your gradient smart object:

[image: Photoshop screenshot: Blending options]

Uncheck **Blend Clipped Layers as Group**:

[image: Photoshop screenshot: Layer Style]

Reduce the fill on your gradient smart object to 0%:

[image: Photoshop screenshot: finished product]

And that should do it for you

[image: Finished product]

Comment: In recent Photoshop versions, "Blend Clipped Layers as Group" has been enabled by default.